# API Documentation for Guzzle?

Tags: guzzle

Where is the API Documentation for Guzzle?

There are these two links (which appear to be the same thing):

- http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html
- http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/

But nowhere can I find in depth API documentation (even just a basic one generated from the Docblocks which were neatly created in Guzzle's source code).

Does anyone know where to find it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sadly, according to the maintainer of Guzzle: "I personally don't find API docs that useful" (ref: https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/750) so he stopped maintaining them in Guzzle 4 and up. There are docs for 3.7 available via the Internet Archive, but that's it.

Comment: Wow that's pretty depressing. I figure it isn't so hard to set up a git hook to rebuild documentation using phpdocumentor or apigen... or hell, even make a nightly cron job to build docs. But maybe that's just me.

Comment: Wow. That's a bit of a rubbish attitude. Still: not going to condemn someone giving back to the community *too much*, and I guess as it's an OS project if ppl felt that strongly about it, they could contribute back? Still: disappointing as contrary to Mr Dowling, the API docs for me are far more useful than any of the rest of the docs provided. Shrug.